# What is the difference between declaring a final variable in an Activity and instantiating it on the onCreate method?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

This:

```
public class LoadingActivity extends Activity  {

      final private ContactManager cm = new ContactManager(this);
      ...
```

vs. this:

```
public class LoadingActivity extends Activity {

    private ContactManager cm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
       cm = new ContactManager(this);
       ...
```

I understand the meaning of final, the variable would not be able to re-instantiate, however I am not sure which pattern to use and how this affects the Garbage Collector? I guess that on the 2nd version I can use onDestroy to notify the Garbage Collector that I am done with the variable. Does that make sense? Is that needed at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the specific case of Android component classes (e.g., `Activity`, `Service`), only use the `final`-plus-initializer approach for cases where you do not need `this`. Methods inherited from the base classes for those components (e.g., `Activity`) may not work until after `super.onCreate()` is called from the `onCreate()` method.

Hence, in your two examples shown above, the second one is correct.

Comment: @ZahanSafallwa: Only refer to an object (e.g., `this` in this case) when it is safe to hand it over to that other class. In this case, an `Activity` or `Service` is not ready until after `super.onCreate()`. *Maybe*` `ContactManager` will not do anything with the `Activity` it receives in the constructor until it is safe to do so, but we do not know that, and `ContactManager` might change in the future. Hence, only create the `ContactManager`, and pass it the `Activity`, when we know that it is safe to do so, after `super.onCreate()`.

Comment: Is it correct in anyway to instantiate variables upon declaration in Activity classes? As I see it the variable declaration part of the Activity is like a constructor in a way, is it not?

Comment: @Guy: "Is it correct in anyway to instantiate variables upon declaration in Activity classes?" -- so long as it is data that does not depend upon the activity instance itself (`this`), it is perfectly fine, just as it is in ordinary Java classes.

Comment: @CommonsWare Got it! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, in Java, it isn't good to use `this` until you have an instance to work with. Using a constructor is the recommended way for method one, but Activity constructors aren't used that way, so pattern 2 is correct in terms of Android code.

If you need to make the variable final, you'd need to wrap it in another Java class where you can properly initialize the variable with a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In first case, you have declared cm variable as final, So you cannot define any new value to this variable. i.e now you cannot write cm = xyz.

In second case you can anytime change the value of cm or reinitialize it with some parameters etc.

**In your case second method will work best**

Comment: The question said that the `final` meaning was understood